# "DNS server not authoritative for zone" error on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, cmd, error-handling, dns

I tried to launch the Python console from `cmd` on a Windows 7 machine and got the cryptic error message

```
C:\>python
DNS server not authoritative for zone.
```

I've never encountered this before and could not find any conclusive explanation. What does this mean?

I installed Python 3.8.5 as well as `pip` using the `get-pip.py` installation script from [here](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/). Doing `C:\>pip -v` throws the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found at least a working solution - although I don't understand it.

The error is reproducible by using `cmd` with *administrator privileges* and does not occur when using the command line with normal privileges, e.g. just typing `cmd` into the search bar of the Windows menu (instead of doing *Right Click on `cmd.exe` > Properties > Compatibility > Check "Run this program as an administrator"*).

Anyone know the technicality behind this?